# What is the status on questions related to Bhargava's factorial function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, cv.complex-variables, special-functions, open-problems

In Manjul Bhargava's [The Factorial Function and Generalizations](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/620F09/Notes/Bhargava/2695734.pdf) he motivates a new type of factorial $n!_S$ using by generalizing a few theorems like:

- For $k, l \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $k! \times l!$ divides $(k+l)!$.
- For any primitive polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $\deg f = k$ then $\mathrm{gcd}\{ f(a): a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ divides $k!$

In the process of solving generalizing these two results, he invents a factorial for any set of integers $S \in \mathbb{Z}$.  For any prime $p$, order the element of $S$ by:

- choose $a_0 \in S$
- find $a_1$ giving the smallest power of $(a_1 - a_0)$
- find $a_2$ giving the smallest power of $(a_2 - a_0)(a_2 - a_1)$
- ...
- find $a_k$ giving the smallest power of $\prod_{i< k} (a_k - a_i)$

One could look for analogues of the gamma function, stirling's approximation, binomial theorem and taylor series expansion of $e$ and indeed, Bhargava mentions these questions towards the end of the paper.

Have any of these questions been answered (partially or otherwise)?

Comment: Why is p needed for the definition?

Comment: What does "find $a_1$ giving the smallest power of $(a_1-a_0)$" mean? [and why would this question get migrated away from math.stackexchange?]

Comment: The paper was published: Bhargava, Manjul, The factorial function and generalizations, Amer. Math. Monthly 107 (2000), no. 9, 783–799, MR1792411 (2002d:05002). The review mentions 5 citations in other reviews, and 30 citations in references in other reviews. If you have access to Math Reviews, tracking those down should keep you busy.  

. 
.

Comment: Bhargava wrote other articles about P-orderings, for example https://eudml.org/doc/153942 and http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2009-22-04/S0894-0347-09-00638-9/ which have generated subsequent work.